# I want to get married with the intention of only having sex?

Tags: nikah, talaq, wife

I'm a 28 yr old(sunni) guy with strong sexual urges, I would like to fulfill them in a halal maner. 
I have been searching for my ideal wife for 3 yrs now but can't find her, I am now considering marrying for sex and either divorcing the first wife or marrying a second wife when or if I find my ideal woman.

Is there anything not permissable with this according to Islam?

Comment: Which school of thought? Sunni or Shia?

Comment: Sunni School of thought

Comment: I know divorce is a grave matter, and so I would prefer this to be with a divorcee or a middle aged woman.

Comment: @mohamed What makes you think it's okay to divorce a divorcee or a middle aged woman? As a muslim, no matter what, you cannot lie to your prospective wife, etc.

Comment: On top of that, if a beautiful woman married you with the intention of leaving you after a few months-- just because she wanted to use you-- would you accept it? Would you feel deceived, lost, etc.? If the answer to all of these yes, then put yourself in the other persons shoes and think about it.

Comment: @Noah as Medi1Saif mentioned if I make my intentions clear to her would it fall under muttah I.e. temporary marriage so say I found a girl that I liked whilst being married to my first wife then I either continue being married to the two if the new girl accepts polygamy or I divorce the first if she doesn't accept.

Comment: @Medi1Saif but making this is aqd al nikah that he will divorse after his DESIRE is fulfilled will make it something like muttah... which is haraam in sunni school of thought.

Comment: @Zia Ul Rehman Mughal you misunderstand the divorcee will only take place if the second wife don't accept to be a co-wife

Comment: In Islam there's no such thing as temporary or conditional (as in this case) marriage. It'd be unfair to your first wife if you did what you have proposed. Why would the first have to get divorced if it's the second not accepting the first? I recommend that you find a woman you can spend your life with. Your chances of you finding that ideal angel are gonna be much more reduced once you get married. That ideal Princess Charming would be looking for her Prince Charming not someone who's already married to another woman.

Comment: After reading some fatawa I'm pretty much supporting the given answer by @M.M. and would add or advise you to search a good wife for marriage without such conditions. Maybe you may need to marry -if possible- a 2nd or even 3rd or 4th wife to fulfill your desires. On the other hand you could also fast to calm them down. Note that you can't marry a 2nd wife if your wife puts a condition not to have an other wife besides her in the 'aqd an-Nikah. You also shouldn't be selfish, so you can't just use a wife like sex object and must be responsible as marriage means building a family!

Answer (score 3):

The majority of scholars see it is permissible to marry with intention of divorce but without being a condition in the contract, if it's mentioned in the marriage contract then the contract is invalid and so is the marriage.

**Mentioned that:**

**Imam Shafei in "Al-Om"**

**Imam Ibn Qudaamah  in "Al-Moghni"**

**Shaikh "Al-Dardir"**

**Shaikh Ibn Taimeya"**

---

**So the answer for your question is: No**, nothing of what you mentioned is not permissable. But you need to know that **Islam did not legislate marriage for that reason**, but for sublime purposes such as starting family and having kids as well as fulfilling the desire in halal way.

It's also **"Makrooh"** and some scholars say **Haram**" to have **divorce without proper reason**.

Allow me to advise you:

I see things are now different from before, divorced woman was normal and no obstacles for her to marry again, nowadays in some communities being divorced woman is not a good thing and her life becomes harder, thus you might want to consider the following:

- Is it **fair** to do marry her only for that purpose then divorce her?
- How will you accept it if someone did the same to your sister?
- Do you realize changing wives is not that simple and you will lose things if you work things that way?

May Allah guide you to the righteous.