# Is this marriage allowed

Tags: nikah, zina

Is this allowed: can I get an escort to convert to Islam, marry her and pay her, be intimate with her and then divorce her afterwards

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

This borderline-haram scheme seems to be a way to have sex without sin.  The husband would need to be a Muslim in order to marry a Muslim woman.  It seems inconsistent for a Muslim man who cares about avoiding sin to implement such a scheme; he's not exactly going to outsmart Allah.

> ... The (reward of) deeds, depend upon the intentions ...-- Sahih al-Bukhari 6689 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/66))

---

Let's break this down:

> can I get an escort to convert to Islam,

Yes, that's allowed regardless of a person's profession.  In fact, it's encouraged in the Qur'an; [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/12376) gives a list.

> marry her

With the usual caveats (one man, one woman; husband is Muslim; woman not yet married; the marriage is legal in the country) then [with her permission](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38270/17163), yes.

In several schools of thought, you may also need her wali's (guardian's) permission.  Not all though; Hanafi being a notable exception.

> pay her

It's permissible to give one's wife money.

> be intimate with her

It's permissible and encouraged to have sex with one's spouse.

> then divorce her afterwards

Divorce is permissible (though discouraged) in Islam; see [Just reciting "Talak" thrice commits divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/103/17163) for the technicalities.  Marrying with the intent to divorce is discouraged, and possibly haram: [I want to get married with the intention of only having sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33260/17163)